# SQL Server: combine maximum result and second largest results in single query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I think this should be easy but I can't figure it out.

Here is some background information:

I have two tables, called Leases and UtilityBills.  They are connected via a foreign key called   LeaseID in the UtilityBills table, which references the primary key (also called LeaseID) in the Leases table.

So that's pretty straightforward--I am recording a monthly electricity meter reading for each of the many leases.

In the UtilityBills table I have a field called MeterReadingDate which is where I store the date when each meter reading was taken.

Here is my question:

How can I create a query which will give me, for each lease, both the date of the most recent meter reading, and the date of the prior meter reading?

I am able to get the most recent meter reading for each lease easily enough, using this sql statement:

```
SELECT LeaseID, MAX(MeterReadingDate) AS MostRecentMeterReadingDate
FROM   dbo.UtilityBills
GROUP BY LeaseID
```

I am also able to get the prior meter reading for any given lease, using this sql statement (for instance, this gives me the prior meter reading for lease with LeaseID=228):

```
SELECT TOP 1 MeterReadingDate, LeaseID
FROM   (SELECT TOP 2 MeterReadingDate, LeaseID
                FROM    dbo.UtilityBills
                WHERE (LeaseID = 228)
                ORDER BY MeterReadingDate DESC) DERIVEDTBL
ORDER BY MeterReadingDate
```

What I can't figure out, is how to combine these two statements to generate a query that lists the second-most recent and the most recent meter reading dates, for all leases.  As far as I can tell, I need to use CROSS APPLY in this situation, but can't get it to work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want both dates in the same row, you can use the ROW_NUMBER() function. You do not need to join the table to itself, just use a group by like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.UtilityBills') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.UtilityBills;

CREATE TABLE dbo.UtilityBills(
Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
LeaseId INT,
MeterReadingDate DATE
);

INSERT INTO dbo.UtilityBills(LeaseId,MeterReadingDate)VALUES 
  (1,'2012-01-01'),
  (1,'2012-02-01'),
  (1,'2012-03-01'),
  (1,'2012-04-01'),
  (2,'2012-01-02'),
  (2,'2012-03-02'),
  (2,'2012-05-02'),
  (3,'2012-08-03'),
  (3,'2012-10-03'),
  (4,'2012-05-04');

SELECT LeaseId,
MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN MeterReadingDate END) MostRecentReadingDate,
MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN MeterReadingDate END) PreviousReadingDate
FROM(
SELECT  LeaseID,
        MeterReadingDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY LeaseId ORDER BY MeterReadingDate DESC ) rn
FROM    dbo.UtilityBills
)AS U
WHERE rn <=2
GROUP BY LeaseId;
```

There are a few other answers here suggesting the RANK() function instead of ROW_NUMBER(). However, if the last two readings happened on the same day RANK() will produce unexpected results.

Comment: user1349242 seems to have gone silent, but this is the best solution.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you on? What SP? (run "SELECT @@VERSION;" and post the result.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response!  It turns out I'm using SQLServer 2000, which I believe doesn't support ROW_NUMBER().  Are there any workarounds that you're aware of?  Or maybe it's just time to upgrade...  Specifically, Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.2305  (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, I think you need to get the most recent 2 readings fro each LeaseID. For that this;

```
SELECT LeaseID, MeterReadingDate
FROM (
    SELECT LeaseID, MeterReadingDate, 
           Rank() Over (Partition by LeaseID Order by MeterReadingDate desc) rk
    FROM   dbo.UtilityBills
) A
WHERE rk <3
ORDER BY MeterReadingDate desc
```

Comment: this will return both in two separate rows and not as one row

Comment: @rs.: Does he say he needs them in two columns?

Comment: From his question i think he wants both in one row OP said - `how to combine these two statements to generate a query that lists the second-most recent and the most recent meter reading dates, for all leases.`

Comment: @rs. it does `NOT` mean a single row. I stick with my initial answer.

Comment: he also mentioned he used `cross apply` on both, which means he is trying to join both query and show result in one row and he failed to get it to work. If he wanted two rows, OP can return `UNION` of two queries. I may be wrong though..

Comment: @rs.: We never know, may be you correct in which case you would get the tick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;WITh CTE AS
(
   SELECT LEASEID, MeterReadingDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                       (PARTITION BY LEASEID 
                        ORDER BY MeterReadingDate DESC) RN
   FROM   dbo.UtilityBills
)
SELECT x1.LEASEID, x1.MeterReadingDate CurrentDate, 
x2.MeterReadingDate PreviousDate
FROM CTE x1
LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE X2 ON x1.leaseid = x2.leaseid AND x1.rn + 1 = x2.rn
WHERE X1.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For your particular problem, you can combine the queries by including the `group by`.  Here is an example:

```
SELECT LeaseID, MIN(MeterReadingDate) as PriorReading, MAX(MeterReadingDate) as LatestReading
FROM   (SELECT TOP 2 MeterReadingDate, LeaseID
        FROM    dbo.UtilityBills
        WHERE (LeaseID = 228)
        ORDER BY MeterReadingDate DESC
       ) DERIVEDTBL
group by leaseid
ORDER BY MeterReadingDate
```

This works for the prior.  For going back longer, you need a more complex solution . . . but that is not your question.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT       
   ls.Id  as 'leaseId',
   ub.MeterReadingDate as 'MeterDate'
FROM Leases ls
    left outer join UtilityBills ub  on   ls.Id = ub.LeaseID
    left outer join UtilityBills ub2 on   ub2.LeaseID=ls.Id 
                                     and  ub2.MeterReadingDate > ub.MeterReadingDate
    left outer join UtilityBills ub3 on   ub3.LeaseID=ls.Id 
                                     and  ub3.MeterReadingDate > ub.MeterReadingDate 
                                     and  ub3.MeterReadingDate < ub2.MeterReadingDate
    left outer join UtilityBills ub4 on   ub4.LeaseID=ls.Id 
                                     and  ub3.Id is null 
                                     and  ub4.MeterReadingDate > ub2.MeterReadingDate 
WHERE ub2.Id is null
   or (ub3.Id is null and ub4.Id is null)
```